# Allow a per tab selection of the layout format

Tags: feature-request, new-nav

I might have strange tastes in formatting, but I always preferred the old-style format of having the homepage show a "collapsed" view of questions, and the rest of the tabs show an "expanded" view. In the new nav system, it seems that the format you chose for one tab is the format for *all* tabs, even the home tab.

I'd prefer the ability to switch between these on a per-tab basis, as sometimes, I just want to see the title of the question (home tab, maybe a search filter), but other times (when I'm looking at the newest questions, for example) I'd like to see the expanded view with both the body and the title. Is it possible for this to be implemented?

Comment: When I read the original title, I thought you wanted page 2 to look different from page 3 :). I like this suggestion though...