# Can we have an option to use the old style questions list, with new-nav tabs?

Tags: feature-request, new-nav

Since the [new-nav](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/new-nav) now is the standard view, would it be possible to opt for the question list to be shown in the old filtered tag style, where just question votes were shown at the left, and a short preview of the question body was rendered (the latter is what I'm missing primarily).

I found this [older question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/312804/allow-a-per-tab-selection-of-the-layout-format) that seems to ask for the same feature. Though I'd like to keep mine, since there wasn't any reaction besides a few upvotes.

---

To illustrate what I'm missing is this format in the list:

[image]

Comment: Well, the dupe should be the other way round, since the target has no answer (I know it possible on meta). It was probably a bad idea proposing it in 1st place. Some moderator likes to fix that please?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can change the list type in the upper right corner of any tab (except home), which will change the view for all tabs, unlike [the linked question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/312804/allow-a-per-tab-selection-of-the-layout-format) that requests to set the view type on a per tab basis.

[image]

Comment: I am unable to find this. I am in the middle of asking a question and it is not there. it is also not on any random Q&A page or on my profile page.  Pls advise. thx!